# How do i map enums in a many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, entity-relationship

I am working on a project, where i have problems transfering my Entity Relashionship Model into Java code.
I am not really sure if i am allowed to post the code here, so i made an example which resembles the problematics i have.

Here is the ERM i created:

[image]

Person and address are both supposed to be classes and a person should have exactly 2 addresses, thats why i chose the two variables, "HomeAdress" and "WorkingAdress" over a list or an array. <s>But therefore i am not sure how to code this relation in Java, or if it's even possible or if i need another approach.</s> (I found a solution for this while writing this question)

Hobbies is supposed to be an enum and a Person can have multiple hobbies or none. And a hobby can be assigned to multiple persons or to none. I am not quite sure how to assign enums in a many to many relationship.

I show you the code i have so far.

Hobbies:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "hobbies")
public enum Hobby {
    FISHING("Fishing"),
    HIKING("Hiking"),
    FOOTBALL("Football"),
    DANCING("Dancing"),
    NETFLIX("Netflix");
    
    private String description;
    
    private Hobby(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

Person class:

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="state", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Address homeAddress;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="state", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Address workingAddress;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="hobbies")
    private Hobby[] hobbies;
}
```

Address class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name= "workingAdress", nullable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name= "homeAddress", nullable = false)
    })
    private Person person;
```

While writing this questions i found the @JoinColumns annotation, which seems to solve one of my problems. Now i can assign two possible join columns to a single variable.
However the problem with mapping the enum still remains. Because i get an org.hibernate.AnnotationException when i run this code. It says No identifier specified for entity: Hobby.

Will i have implement an id for the enum? Can't i use the enum value as id? Or maybe the whole mapping is bogus. I hope you can help me.

Also i am happy for any advices you can give to me. Because i am very new to coding and i try to improve as much as i can.

Comment: I found an mistake i made, since the relationship between the person and the address isn't really one to many or many to one, it's just one to one as i have separate variables for the two addresses and one address only belonging to one person.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after another whole day of trying out different things and trying to find a solution i gave up and made Hobby a class instead of an enum. Now it is working fine.
It seems like making arrays or collections of enums to persist with hibernate is a bad practice. As it's very hard to find any information on it on the internet and if you find a thread about it, it's 10 years old and the solution doesn't work anymore.